# Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design version 6.0.1 when trying to run app after publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm facing issues with an ASP.NET Core 6 web app that has multiple projects and some of them have Views and Controllers due to requirements, so I marked them with as `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">` and added application parts in the Startup as follows:

[image]

Due to the fact I run Scaffolding command line to build entity classes based on SQL Server Database, to create also the migration files, I use a technique to have entities singularized/pluralized at design-time when they are created. To achieve that I had to use DesignTime services provided by **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design** by creating the **DesignTimeDbContextFactory**, **DesignTimeServices** and **Pluralizer** classes to provide db-connection and pluralization services, so I added Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design package to the main project and to the backend (dbcontext repository) project.

To avoid this package copied to the output publishing folder (this package should not be part of production), I added following configuration in the csproj of the projects referencing the package, according internet documentation found:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <!--<IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>-->
    </PackageReference>
```

The problem comes out when I try to run the published project by running dotnet SicotX.dll command-line (is the main project). The app try to run but do nothing

[image]

I check the logs I added to the app, and this is the list of stack trace:

```
2022-03-02T21:31:07.8101308-05:00 [INF] () Creating the web host ...
2022-03-02T21:31:09.0961070-05:00 [FTL] (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics) Application startup exception
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart.get_Types()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetControllerTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Subscribe>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.Subscribe()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource..ctor(ControllerActionEndpointDataSourceIdProvider dataSourceIdProvider, IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actions, ActionEndpointFactory endpointFactory, OrderedEndpointsSequenceProvider orderSequence)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllerRoute(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, String name, String pattern, Object defaults, Object constraints, Object dataTokens)
   at SicotX.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__6_2(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoint) in D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Enterprise\.Net\SicotX\SicotX\Frontend\SicotX\Startup.cs:line 266
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at SicotX.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory log) in D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Enterprise\.Net\SicotX\SicotX\Frontend\SicotX\Startup.cs:line 264
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
File name: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
2022-03-02T21:31:09.6087813-05:00 [FTL] () A fatal error ocurred creating the web host.
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart.get_Types()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFeatureProvider.PopulateFeature(IEnumerable`1 parts, ControllerFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.ApplicationPartManager.PopulateFeature[TFeature](TFeature feature)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetControllerTypes()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Subscribe>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.ChangeToken.OnChange(Func`1 changeTokenProducer, Action changeTokenConsumer)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ActionEndpointDataSourceBase.Subscribe()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing.ControllerActionEndpointDataSource..ctor(ControllerActionEndpointDataSourceIdProvider dataSourceIdProvider, IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider actions, ActionEndpointFactory endpointFactory, OrderedEndpointsSequenceProvider orderSequence)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.GetOrCreateDataSource(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.ControllerEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.MapControllerRoute(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoints, String name, String pattern, Object defaults, Object constraints, Object dataTokens)
   at SicotX.Startup.<>c.<Configure>b__6_2(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpoint) in D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Enterprise\.Net\SicotX\SicotX\Frontend\SicotX\Startup.cs:line 266
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.EndpointRoutingApplicationBuilderExtensions.UseEndpoints(IApplicationBuilder builder, Action`1 configure)
   at SicotX.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory log) in D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Enterprise\.Net\SicotX\SicotX\Frontend\SicotX\Startup.cs:line 264
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<Build>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<UseStartup>b__1(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters.MiddlewareFilterBuilderStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>g__MiddlewareFilterBuilder|0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFilteringStartupFilter.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostService.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
   at SicotX.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Proyectos\Repositorios\Enterprise\.Net\SicotX\SicotX\Frontend\SicotX\Program.cs:line 47
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.
File name: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=6.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'
```

I'm looking in all projects to see if some of them are also referencing this package but only the main project and the backend project were marked in the csproj as mentioned above.

I'm trying to search if the problem is caused by any application part loaded in the startup but no success.

Important: My goal is to avoid Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design published to production since that package only works in design-time and overcome the log errors I'm facing according the things I've been doing.

I'm not facing issues while debugging.

I appreciate any help

Comment: Make sure that each project referenced pulls in the same major/minor version of the Entity Framework Core nuget package.

Comment: This looks like a bug in MVC. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.AssemblyPart.get_Types()` should be more resilient to types that may not be fully available at runtime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Workaround

After analyzing alternatives, I achieved to overcome the issue by doing following:

After checking out that DEBUG conditional directive is enabled only for Debug:

[image]

I used the compilation directives in all code referencing **Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design** package, to avoid that final published assemblies would require to have this package in the output directory, and because publishing is in release mode, the code was supressed, like this:

[image]

Now, the app is working as expected.